# Image View 16:9 aspect ratio

Tags: ios, xcode, uistoryboard, nslayoutconstraint, aspect-ratio

I want all of my images in a specific Image View to fit in a 16:9 aspect ratio. The image should resize to fit itself into those contraints without changing its own aspect ratio.

So for example, if I have an image with an aspect ratio of 4:3, it should resize itself, while keeping its aspect ratio, to the Image View's contraints of 16:9.

So my question is, using the interface builder, how do I set an Image View to have a 16:9 aspect ratio?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Steps:**

1. Add a **Width constraint** and an **Aspect Ratio constraint** like below: *(**NOTE:** You can also do with leading, trailing constraints -- they resolve the X position. For solving the Y position, you can add either top or bottom constraint (OR) an **Align Center Y** constraint.):*

[image: Constraints]

2. Select your image view and go to the **Size Inspector**, select edit for the aspect ratio constraint you just added, and input 16:9 to the multiplier there. Aaannddd you are done.

---

If you change the width constraint, the height will automatically change respecting the aspect ratio. **Make sure you set your `ImageView`'s content mode to be `scaleAspectFill`.**

[image: Edit Aspect Ratio]

Comment: Instead of setting a width constraint, can I set normal Leading and Trailing constraints?

Comment: Yes of course. You can do leading, trailing -- they resolve the X position. For Y, you can add either top or bottom constraint OR an **Align Center Y** constraint.

Answer (score 4):

**iOS 13, swift 5.1**

If someone wants to do it with **programmatic constraints**, this is the recipe.

```
imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
```

A) 4:3

```
imageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: widthAnchor, multiplier: 3.0/4.0).isActive = true
```

B) 16:9

```
imageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: widthAnchor, multiplier: 9.0/16.0).isActive = true
```

Comment: shouldn't this be 16/9 instead of 9/16

Comment: I know, but it get's inverted. Upvote me if it works for you.